# Bootstrap 4 - multiple select does not highlight entire item when overflowing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When using Bootstrap 4's form-control on a multiple select element, I'm having an issue with how a selected item is rendered when it overflows.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <select multiple style="overflow-x: auto;" class="form-control">
      <option>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</option>
      <option>123</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I select the `asdf...` option, the blue highlight shows up for part of the item, but then as you scroll right it does not continue and the rest of the text is white on a white background which makes it very difficult to read.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwurfcmx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the right approach but you can fix it by changing the **display** property of option tag

```
option{
  display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting overflow on `form-control` itself, rather set `overflow: auto;` to your `col-3` class which is the wrapper of `form-control`. Also, `width: auto;` should be explicitly set for `form-control` otherwise it won't work.

Hope this fixes the issue:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.col-3 {
  overflow: auto;
}

.form-control {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <select multiple class="form-control">
      <option>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</option>
      <option>123</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qje6kLu/12/).

Comment: It works fine without bootstrap cdn. But if you add a reference to `bootstrap.min.css` it breaks.

Comment: Thank you - but the answer by creativenitish was more in line with what I was looking for because I wanted the select element itself to scroll, sorry if I wasn't clear in my post. This is a good option as well